# How to disable modules using the admin UI?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

Good afternoon, please help me to solve the next problem. There is a site in work, after transfer from one hosting to another something went wrong. ALL modules are disabled. You can turn on the module, but you can not turn it off. Only by deleting via drush. Can I somehow reset ALL site settings without deleting the taxonomy and content?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the image you posted, you are using Drupal 8 and you are on the module enabling page.
The modules listing in the image (with a ticked checkbox) are enabled.

Unlike Drupal 7, you do not have to disable a module before you uninstall it. This is why the enabled modules on the page you posted can not be unchecked.

In drupal 8, to disable modules, you do it directly on the module uninstall page at:

```
/admin/modules/uninstall
```